# CompositionBatch.AddExportedValue with type specified

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, mef

I set up the container as follows:

```
....
CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
CompositionBatch batch = new CompositionBatch();

batch.AddExportedValue(_dataClient);
batch.AddExportedValue(_orderClient);
batch.AddExportedValue(container);
container.Compose(batch);
```

`_dataClient` and `_orderClient` are in a different assembly and I can't touch them. However they implement `IDataFeed` and `IOrderFeed` respectively (However their types are `DataClient` and `OrderClient` respectively). Later I expect them in a constructor:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public ShellViewModel(IShellView view, IDataFeed dataFeed, IOrderFeed orderFeed)
...
```

But this throws an `ImportCardinalityMismatchException`. However if I change the constructor to this it works:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public ShellViewModel(IShellView view, DataClient dataFeed, OrderClient orderFeed)
...
```

I tried this but the same exception was raised:

```
...
batch.AddExportedValue(typeof(IDataFeed).FullName, _dataClient);
batch.AddExportedValue(typeof(IOrderFeed).FullName, _orderClient);
...
```

How can I add `_dataClient` and `_orderClient` to the container as if I did this:

```
[Export(typeof(IDataFeed))]
public class DataClient : IDataFeed
{
    ...
```

How do I do this? Ideally something like this:

```
batch.AddExportedValue(typeof(IDataFeed), _dataClient);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was easy. Don't know how I missed that.

```
batch.AddExportedValue((IDataFeed)_dataClient);
```